# jq google map how to hide coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, maps

Sorry but I'm a beginner at web developing ><

can someone please tell me how can I hide these coordinates?

here's the code

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=34.430963,35.829522&amp;num=1&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.431018,35.8296&amp;spn=0.001341,0.002642&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

and here's the website I'm trying to create
[www.mashawi-restaurant.com](http://mashawi-restaurant.com)

here's the image to clarify more 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/spqwyxhnn3cvb9f/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the API, like with this site here: http://www.addmap.org/

I've looked around and there doesn't seem to be a way to remove the coordinates from the `iframe`.